# Present simple or past simple?

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me which tense should I use in such phrase :

> I'd try to add him to the group and check if it ______ (helps / helped) ?
>
> I'd try to add him to the group and check if it ______ (works / worked) ?

Answer (score 1):

While you could be understood with either tense, the actual meaning here suggests a third option: present perfect. As you are checking if an action that occurred previously has an effect in the present you can use the present perfect

> What is your suggestion?
>
> I would try to add him to the group and check if it has helped.

But you'll be understood with other tenses. And I'm sure there are examples of native speakers using either past or present in this situation.

Comment: Why you changed I'd to I'll ? I wanted to express what I would do if I have to do it myself

Comment: Ah, got it. I'd interpreted it as "I had try to ..."  (which is ungrammatical)